# absolute continuous in two dimension

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am doing a problem on measure theory and probability theory, which is from the book Theory of Point Estimation, Chapter 1, probelm 3.1.

The problem is that: Let X have standard normal distribution and let Y=2X. Determine whether

(a) the cdf $F(x,y)$ of $(X,Y)$ is continuous

(b) the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure in the $(x,y)$ plane.

I can find the cdf $$F(x,y)=P(X<min(x,y/2))=\int_{-\infty}^{min(x,y/2)}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-s^2/2}ds.$$

For (a), I think $F(x,y)$ is continuous. But for (b), on one hand, I think we need to use the relation that absolute continuous of a measure is equivalent to the absolute continuous of the CDF that used generated it. So, I think for (b), we need to show $F(x,y)$ is absolute continuous. But, on the other hand, I don't know what is the definition of absolute continuous for a two dimensional function, and how to show whether it is a absolute continuous or not.

Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could anybody help me please? Thank you!